# UITable cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone

New in iOS, here is Question:

I am using `xcode 4.0.2 iso-4.3.2`.
Here I have a table and I am creating one mutable array like

```
mainarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hi",@"Hello"nil];
```

and sending that value to.Table delegate method like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

here value is coming but once I am sending dynamically value to the mainarray like

```
mainarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[dataarray valueForKey:@"first_name"],nil]; or
[mainarray addobject:[dataarray valueForKey:@"first_name"]]
```

and sending that mainarray value to `cell.textlabel.text` then my program is terminating and sending this error message.

```
2011-05-11 10:29:10.346 picture:vide[742:207] -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e85200
2011-05-11 10:29:10.348 picture:vide[742:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e85200'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00ddb5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f2f313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00ddd0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d4c966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d4c522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x003ecafc -[UILabel setText:] + 72
    6   picture:vide                        0x000050c9 -[VideoChatController1 tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 376
    7   UIKit                               0x00340b98 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 634
    8   UIKit                               0x003364cc -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x0034b8cc -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
    10  UIKit                               0x0034390c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
    11  QuartzCore                          0x01d7ba5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01d7dddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01d230b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    14  QuartzCore                          0x01d24294 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    15  QuartzCore                          0x01d2446d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00dbc89b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d516e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00d1a1d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00d19840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00d19761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x017321c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x01732289 GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x002d9c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  picture:vide                        0x00002910 main + 102
    25  picture:vide                        0x000028a1 start + 53
)
```

Please, help.

Comment: Pls check you naming [dataarray valueForKey:@"first_name"] dataarray name suggest its an array but i guess its a dictionary. Naming conventions are there for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are getting this terminating log because

dataArray is an NSArray you can't call `[dataarray valueForKey:@"first_name"]` this
because this unreconised for NSArray

rether than this you may use some thing like this

```
[[dataarray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"first_name"]
```

Comment: he doesnt say dataArray is NSArray. I guess its just his naming is wrong... Good point though but i guess he would have a received a warning if its an array

Comment: @7KV7 yap it gives a warning but not give any error only this kind of crash log when he runs.I face this problem lot of time when forget to rightly access this kind of data from array

Answer (score 0):

`[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]:` is the issue. You are using the `isEqualToString:` for an array somewhere. Check that. Its a method of `NSString`

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of array was wrong.

Following line

```
mainarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hi",@"Hello"nil];
```

should be corrected as

```
mainarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hi",@"Hello" , nil];
```

Please note the new comma between **@"Hello"** and **nil**